# Where are my bitcoins - unconfirmed transactions

Tags: bitcoin-core, utxo

Using Bitcoin Core wallet, I sent coins to an address of mine outside of the wallet. All three transactions sit as unconfirmed though show in blockchain.

https://blockchain.info/address/1HYK6Key5EUwAyaxh6SniXKEjSMsPAgY94

they are the bottom three transactions. Not sure why they are showing as "spent" - I did send about 0.65btc to this wallet after which I then spent.

So in short - the bottom three transactions are showing as unconfirmed on BitcoinCore, the btc is not in the account they were sent to. Where are they?

Further info - the bottom 2 of the 3 transactions were sent almost a week ago though didn't show up in blockchain until I reinstalled the wallet app. However, BTW is still nowhere to be found. Fees - bottom two were sent minimum, top of the 3 was sent as recommended and all are showing as "0/unconfirmed" in the wallet app

Comment: the precise transation IDs are: d3f86df12c12801ca97244a773287226fd1e833e7151b1ab3a90bff930351e50-000     ---   2c1f5f44d33505eeb2780866626745511e293f60aa8a79c9ef507dfc6317f096-000    -----  90f701b16cc7fd3c463f82f2ec70b80b6a361f18833087bc0731d045787d8fdc-000

Comment: Does no one know what the issue is? Seems a bit basic that when I send coins from wallet A to wallet B they ought to arrive...

Answer (score 0):

The transaction d3f86df12c12801ca97244a773287226fd1e833e7151b1ab3a90bff930351e50 has a zero fee, so I doubt it will be confirmed anytime soon. Do you know how to double spend it and specify a higher fee?

The other two transactions also have a very low transaction fee but that would still be OK. The problem is that they are spending from the zero fee transaction. Therefore they cannot become confirmed before the parent with zero fee is confirmed.

You say that you sent those transaction a week ago, but Blockchain shows that it received them yesterday. Maybe they were dropped from the mempool after some days last week and now your wallet did just rebroadcast them. What wallet do you use?

Comment: thanks , this has now been confirmed. I sent the btc literally 10 days, straight after I sent another which went through fine. The zero fee transaction basically sat there and did nothing and hadn't registered for a week and half on blockchain. I reinstalled the wallet software, using an older backup of the wallet before this transaction(just reinstalling with doing a bitcoin synch using the current wallet STILL did not send the transaction through!) Once I did a fresh install, using an old wallet, the wallet software finally sent the zero cost transaction and everything else then processed.

Comment: In short, there is clearly an issue with Bitcoin Core. I sent a transaction to this precise address which went through fine, then two hours later I sent another transaction with zero fee (which I always do!) and that transaction did not at all register on blockchain. Had to do the above to get it to register. Seems like a fairly serious failure - and since it would not register using the wallet saved after I sent it and required an old wallet before these transactions to register on blockchain it's a bit of a serious error

Comment: I would advise against sending any transaction with zero fee. There is no longer any incentive for a miner to include a zero fee transaction and with the standard settings those zero fee transactions will not even be propagated through the network.